# 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate and the pods could not start

Tags: kubernetes

Preiously pods used to run on nodes without any issue in Azure. Now all of a sudden I am facing this issue.

[Node information available here for which I am facing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InQSe.png)

Please suggest on how to handle this issue?

Comment: Seems like your node is down. As it look like you're running on Azure, look for the VMSS in the MC_ resource group and turn it on (might not be possible if you've run out of credits).

Comment: @mmking  I am not able to find my node in VMSS section.

Comment: did you try restarting the worker nodes ?

Comment: Did you perform any updates on the node? You can try to [drain node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#use-kubectl-drain-to-remove-a-node-from-service)  and restarting it. Kubelet is not running on the node.

Comment: VMSS is a wrapper around some number of VMs (nodes) - it simplifies scaling. Make sure the VMSS is running.

Comment: Thanks, After restarting the nodes, issue got resolved.

Comment: Please consider posting your solution as an answer, it might helpful for others who come across same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution from comments as community wiki for better visibility:

To resolve

```
1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate and the pods could not start
kubelet stopped posting node status
```

the easiest solution is to restart the node.

To do it safely it is recommended to use [`kubectl drain <node-name>`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/safely-drain-node/#use-kubectl-drain-to-remove-a-node-from-service) and then restarting the node.